# Use of dplyr::sym() within "mutation" while creating a list tibble column results in an error is_symbol(x): object '.x' not found

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, tibble

In the following code I try to create a list tibble column at the right end of `mtcars`, in which: each member of the list is a tibble with rows of mtcars tibble where `vs >= 1` and `!is.na(gear)`.

In `purrr::map2()`, I am using `!!dplyr::sym()` to convert the input strings to tibble variables for use in `dplyr::filter()` and `tidyr::drop_na()`, but this results in an error of

> "object '.x' not found".

Why is this happening?

I know that if I use `dplyr::filter_at(.x, ~ {.x >= 1})` and `tidyr::drop_na(all_of(.y))`, I can avoid this error. But is there anything wrong if I want to convert the arguments `.x` and `.y` from strings to tibble variables and use them in `filter()` and `drop_na()`? (I remember they accept unquoted tibble variables)

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  tibble::as_tibble() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(vs2 = purrr::map2("vs", "gear", ~ {
    mtcars %>%
      tibble::as_tibble() %>%
      dplyr::filter(!!dplyr::sym(.x) >= 1) %>%
      tidyr::drop_na(!!dplyr::sym(.y))
  }))
#> Error in is_symbol(x): object '.x' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

My session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.5.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.8.3     purrr_0.3.3     readr_1.3.1    
 [6] tidyr_1.0.2     tibble_2.1.3    ggplot2_3.2.1   tidyverse_1.3.0 shiny_1.4.0.2  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3       lubridate_1.7.4  lattice_0.20-38  ps_1.3.2         assertthat_0.2.1
 [6] digest_0.6.23    mime_0.8         R6_2.4.1         cellranger_1.1.0 backports_1.1.5 
[11] reprex_0.3.0     evaluate_0.14    httr_1.4.1       pillar_1.4.3     rlang_0.4.6     
[16] lazyeval_0.2.2   readxl_1.3.1     rstudioapi_0.10  miniUI_0.1.1.1   whisker_0.4     
[21] callr_3.4.2      rmarkdown_2.1    munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.5.5      compiler_3.6.0  
[26] httpuv_1.5.3.1   modelr_0.1.6     xfun_0.11        pkgconfig_2.0.3  clipr_0.7.0     
[31] htmltools_0.4.0  tidyselect_1.0.0 fansi_0.4.0      crayon_1.3.4     dbplyr_1.4.2    
[36] withr_2.1.2      later_1.0.0      grid_3.6.0       nlme_3.1-139     jsonlite_1.6    
[41] xtable_1.8-4     gtable_0.3.0     lifecycle_0.1.0  DBI_1.1.0        magrittr_1.5    
[46] scales_1.1.0     cli_2.0.0        stringi_1.4.3    fs_1.3.1         promises_1.1.0  
[51] xml2_1.2.2       vctrs_0.2.4      generics_0.0.2   tools_3.6.0      glue_1.3.1      
[56] hms_0.5.2        processx_3.4.2   fastmap_1.0.1    colorspace_1.4-1 rvest_0.3.5     
[61] knitr_1.26       haven_2.2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use `!! rlang::sym` in a `map` call nested inside `mutate` (it only works within the top level of `mutate`. You can either write a custom funcion, where you use `!! rlang::sym()` and call this within `map2`. Or you could use `eval` instead of `!!`.

Below is an option using a custom function. However, I am not sure how your desired output looks like. Also, using a string of length 1 in a `map` call, doesn't make much sense, since we could produce the same outcome without `map`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

filter_df <- function(x, y) {
  mtcars %>% 
    tibble::as_tibble() %>%
    dplyr::filter(!! rlang::sym(x) >= 1,
                  !is.na(!! rlang::sym(y)))
}

mtcars %>%
  tibble::as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(vs2 = map2("vs", "gear", filter_df))

#> # A tibble: 32 x 12
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb vs2        
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>     
#>  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 <tibble [1~
#>  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4 <tibble [1~
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1 <tibble [1~
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1 <tibble [1~
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2 <tibble [1~
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1 <tibble [1~
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4 <tibble [1~
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2 <tibble [1~
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2 <tibble [1~
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4 <tibble [1~
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note that you can produce the same outcome by just calling the custom function inside `mutate` wrapped in `list` (you might need dplyr 1.0.0 for this functinonality):

```r
mtcars %>%
  tibble::as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(vs2 = list(filter_df("vs", "gear")))
```

This would be an alternative using `eval` and `map2`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  tibble::as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(vs2 = map2("vs", "gear",
                    ~ mtcars %>% 
                      tibble::as_tibble() %>%
                      dplyr::filter(eval(rlang::sym(.x)) >= 1,
                                    !is.na(eval(rlang::sym(.y))))
                    )
         )
#> # A tibble: 32 x 12
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb vs2        
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>     
#>  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 <tibble [1~
#>  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4 <tibble [1~
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1 <tibble [1~
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1 <tibble [1~
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2 <tibble [1~
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1 <tibble [1~
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4 <tibble [1~
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2 <tibble [1~
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2 <tibble [1~
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4 <tibble [1~
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Add on**

Since the OP shows a very minimal example, here is a more realistic approach where the `tibble` contains a character column with variable names. In this case `map` is no longer needed under `dplyr >= 1.0.0`, since we can use `rowwise` and `mutate`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

filter_df <- function(df, x) {
  df %>% 
    tibble::as_tibble() %>%
    dplyr::filter(!! rlang::sym(x) >= mean(!! rlang::sym(x)))
}

tibble(data = list(tibble(mtcars)),
       var_names = names(mtcars)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(new_data = list(filter_df(data, var_names)))

#> # A tibble: 11 x 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    data               var_names new_data          
#>    <list>             <chr>     <list>            
#>  1 <tibble [32 × 11]> mpg       <tibble [14 × 11]>
#>  2 <tibble [32 × 11]> cyl       <tibble [14 × 11]>
#>  3 <tibble [32 × 11]> disp      <tibble [15 × 11]>
#>  4 <tibble [32 × 11]> hp        <tibble [15 × 11]>
#>  5 <tibble [32 × 11]> drat      <tibble [18 × 11]>
#>  6 <tibble [32 × 11]> wt        <tibble [16 × 11]>
#>  7 <tibble [32 × 11]> qsec      <tibble [15 × 11]>
#>  8 <tibble [32 × 11]> vs        <tibble [14 × 11]>
#>  9 <tibble [32 × 11]> am        <tibble [13 × 11]>
#> 10 <tibble [32 × 11]> gear      <tibble [17 × 11]>
#> 11 <tibble [32 × 11]> carb      <tibble [15 × 11]>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much. This problem emerged when recently I started to use list columns. Previously this function worked perfectly fine in ordinary columns (outside map() function), but when used inside map() it started to cause some problems. Thanks again.

Comment: For the length of the arguments that were passed to the mutated column, it should be either ONE or the number of rows as the input tibble (mtcars in this case). Since mtcars have many rows (32 I think), I am just too lazy to create a list of length 32 for the column, so I just created a list of length 1 to let it recycle through the mutated list column for ease.

However, passing an argument of length 1 to map() function does not affect me from figuring out why sym() is not working within map() in this case.

Comment: Also, using eval() instead of !! in this case can also solve the problem. I was just too lazy to type eval(), and I'll now be more diligent on typing them if needed. Thanks~

Comment: Since you only provide a very minimal example, I just added a more realistic application using `dplyr 1.0.0` with `rowwise` and `mutate` (`map` is no longer needed). However, this doesn't change the way `sym` works.

Comment: Great, the rowwise() fuction adds a handy tool to apply functions rowise. Now I cannot live without these tidyverse functions, but need to use bunches of map() functions when dealing with list columns.

Comment: But in this context, !! still does not work if I integrate the function into the mutate() call, since it is not in the top level of mutate(). Anyway, using eval() is still fine though~ Thanks for providing the various solutions.

Answer (score -2):

[`dplyr::sym`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/tidyeval.html) creates a symbol from a *string*; you'd have to write `dplyr::sym(".x")`.

Comment: No. `.x` is already a string. `dplyr::sym(".x")` doesn't make sense.

Comment: He passes the strings `"vs", "gear"` to `map2` - using `sym(.x)` is ok here.